# Doctrine: Define many-to-many relation inline in fixture

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, foreign-key-relationship, fixtures

I want to know the correct way of defining many-to-many relations inline in a Doctrine Fixture. Consider `sfDoctrineGuardPlugin` for example. The schema can be found [here](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin/branches/1.3/config/doctrine/schema.yml)

I'm defining a fixture like:
I already have 2 groups in the sfGuardGroup table, so I wish to refer the group_id

```
sfGuardUser:
  soc-sfUser-1:
    first_name: Mrs
    last_name: Balasubramanium
    email_address: balasubramanium@gmail.com
    username: balasubramanium@gmail.com
    password: admin
    Groups: [{group_id: 2}]
    is_active: 1
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are also defining the groups in that fixture, you can reference them by name:

```
sfGuardGroup:
  GroupAdmin:  ...
  GroupEditor:  ...

sfGuardUser:
  ...
  Groups: [GroupEditor]
```

If you want to specify an actual ID you should write it this way:

```
sfGuardUser:
  foo:
    first_name:     Foo
    last_name:      Bar
    ...
    sfGuardUserGroup: [{group_id: 2}]
```

Why? If you take a look at the `schema.yml` file of sfDoctrineGuardPlugin you can see a `refClass` property on `sfGuardUser` relations:

```
relations:
  Groups:
    ...
    refClass: sfGuardUserGroup
```

It's a little tricky and not so well documented in Doctrine, but it seems to work.

Comment: Yes, aware of that. But my groups are loaded prior to the users (not in the same data:load task or transaction), so I need to refer to groups using static IDs. Thanks anyways

Comment: @Prasad I think I found the solution. At least it worked for me in some tests I did.

Comment: thanks a ton! Hope based on your 1st reply, Groups: [ { name: Test Group} ] will also work

Comment: @Prasad Interesting... I cannot find an explanation on how it can link the objects using `name` but not the id. Is it me or Doctrine documentation is not completed with all these things?

Comment: @elitalon: not really. It has an explanation. When you refer using Groups, it expects reference to a group or creation of an inline object. So Groups: [GroupEditor] and Groups: [{name: GroupEditorName}] both work. In the latter, the object is defined inline, without a reference. So it cannot be referred in another model.

Comment: This is an interesting piece for reading: http://test.ical.ly/2010/06/18/symfony-workshop-inline-relation-definition-in-fixtures-files-for-doctrine-records/